# linux command-line update csv file inline using value from another column that is json

Tags: json, linux, shell, csv, awk

I have a large csv file that contains several columns.  One of the columns is a json string.  I am trying to extract a specific value from the column that contains the json and add that value to the row as it's own column.

I've tinkered around a little with `sed` and `awk` to try to do this but really I'm just spinning my wheels

I'm also trying to do this as an inline file edit.  The csv is tab delimited.

The value I'm trying to put in its own column is the value for `destinationIDUsage`

Sample row (highly trimmed down for readability here):

```
2017-03-22  00:00:01    %key%94e901fd3ceef351a0ad770e0be91d38   10  3.0.0   [{"MC_LIVEREPEATER":false},{"environment":"details"},{"feature":"pushPublishUsage","destinationIDUsage":876543}]    false
```

End result for the row should now have 876543 as a value in its own column as such:

```
2017-03-22  00:00:01    %key%94e901fd3ceef351a0ad770e0be91d38   10  3.0.0   [{"MC_LIVEREPEATER":false},{"environment":"details"},{"feature":"pushPublishUsage","destinationIDUsage":876543}]    876543  false
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the value you want to extract (i.e 876543) in the same position among all records of your file?

Comment: it's possible that new objects will be added to the json, so it's not guaranteed to always been in the same position

Comment: In this case you need to search for "destinationIDUsage",right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: In the meanwhile you can add awk tag in your question and you will get some good awk suggestions for sure

Comment: 2 very important points - 1) You never need sed when you're using awk so never consider a "sed + awk" solution, 2) The only UNIX editor that doesn't use a tmp file is "ed" (it uses an internal buffer the size of your input file instead) so there really is no such thing as "inplace editing" for the common general purpose text manipulation tools (sed, awk, perl, etc.), you are using a tmp file so don't make whether the tool is using it behind the scenes or you are specifying it manually a priority - it's completely unimportant compared to all other considerations when choosing a tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems that does the job.

```
$ echo "$a"
2017-03-22  00:00:01    %key%94e901fd3ceef351a0ad770e0be91d38   10  3.0.0   [{MC_LIVEREPEATER:false},{environment:details},{feature:pushPublishUsage,destinationIDUsage:876543}]    false

$ echo "$a" |awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~/destinationIDU/) {match($i,/(.*)(destinationIDUsage:)(.*)(})/,f);extra=f[3]}}}{prev=NF;$(NF+1)=$prev;$(NF-1)=extra}1'
2017-03-22 00:00:01 %key%94e901fd3ceef351a0ad770e0be91d38 10 3.0.0 [{MC_LIVEREPEATER:false},{environment:details},{feature:pushPublishUsage,destinationIDUsage:876543}] 876543 false
```

Is possible though, awk experts inhere to propose something different and maybe better.

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-specific for the 3rd arg to `match()`.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {match($6,/"destinationIDUsage":([0-9]+)/,a); $NF=a[1] OFS $NF}1' file
2017-03-22      00:00:01        %key%94e901fd3ceef351a0ad770e0be91d38   10      3.0.0   [{"MC_LIVEREPEATER":false},{"environment":"details"},{"feature":"pushPublishUsage","destinationIDUsage":876543}]      876543  false
```

Add `-i inplace` for "inplace" editing or just do `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` like you can with any UNIX tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
  split("\n")[]                              # split string into lines
| select(length>0)                           # eliminate blanks
| split("\t")                                # split data rows by tabs
| (.[5] | fromjson | add) as $f              # expand json
| .[:-1] + [$f.destinationIDUsage] + .[-1:]  # add destinationIDUsage column
| @tsv                                       # convert to tab-separated
```

and `data` contains the sample data then the command

```
jq -M -R -s -r -f filter.jq data
```

will produce the output with the additional column

```
2017-03-22  00:00:01    %key%94e901fd3ceef351a0ad770e0be91d38   10  3.0.0   [{"MC_LIVEREPEATER":false},{"environment":"details"},{"feature":"pushPublishUsage","destinationIDUsage":876543}]    876543  false
```

To edit the file inplace you can make use of a tool like **sponge** as described in this answer:

- [Manipulate JSON with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166330/manipulate-json-with-jq/41171245#41171245)