# jq - add new field with updating whole file

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I have json file which is constructed in simmilar way:

```
[
{
"_id":"1234",
"org":"org1",
"int":
    {"url":"http://url.com.uk:1234"}},
{
"_id":"4321",
"org":"org2",
"int":
    {"url":"http://url.com.us:4321"}},
...
]
```

Now im "jumping" from one entry to another and checking if under URL application is working properly. After check i want to add/update field "status". But i can't update whole file, im just getting:

```
$ jq --arg mod "GOOD" '.[0].int + {stat: $mod}' tmp.json
{
  "url": "http://url.com.uk:1234",
  "stat": "GOOD"
}
```

How can i with jq command get new updated **whole** file, not just only part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your data in `data.json` and the changes you want to make to
each record into a separate `arg.json` argument file like

```
{
    "1234": { "int": { "stat": "GOOD" } },
    "4321": { "int": { "stat": "BAD", "xxx": "yyy" } }
}
```

and run jq as

```
$ jq -M --argfile arg arg.json 'map(. + $arg[._id])' data.json
```

then it will output the updated data, e.g.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "org": "org1",
    "int": {
      "stat": "GOOD"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "4321",
    "org": "org2",
    "int": {
      "stat": "BAD",
      "xxx": "yyy"
    }
  }
]
```

Note that the `+` replaces keys.  If you want to merge keys you can use `*` e.g.

```
$ jq -M --argfile arg arg.json 'map(. * $arg[._id])' data.json
```

which generates

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "org": "org1",
    "int": {
      "url": "http://url.com.uk:1234",
      "stat": "GOOD"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "4321",
    "org": "org2",
    "int": {
      "url": "http://url.com.us:4321",
      "stat": "BAD",
      "xxx": "yyy"
    }
  }
]
```

If you want to update the data in place you could use [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge)
as described in the answer [Manipulate JSON with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166330/manipulate-json-with-jq/41171245#41171245_)
e.g.

```
$ jq -M --argfile arg arg.json 'map(. * $arg[._id])' data.json | sponge data.json
```

Comment: Dang, this would have been a great addition to [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working for me but it looks more like workaround than proper solution. In bash it should be easier than in programming languages (i can't use any with this, it need to be bash) and in that case it is not. With json library or even in mongoDB JS it is just one line to add/update needed field. Thought there will be some switch with which i can force to push to output all input with updates like "sed" is doing. Have no idea what is the reason why jq is cutting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can map to **array** and resign the `int` by operation, like:

```
jq --arg mod "GOOD" '.[] | .int=.int + {stat: $mod}' tmp.json

{
  "_id": "1234",
  "org": "org1",
  "int": {
    "url": "http://url.com.uk:1234",
    "stat": "GOOD"
  }
}
{
  "_id": "4321",
  "org": "org2",
  "int": {
    "url": "http://url.com.us:4321",
    "stat": "GOOD"
  }
}
```

Comment: I need output for whole file and update every segment separately  with proper state (no same state for every segment like in your example).

Comment: @user3069488, I think you can use `select` for this, like: `jq --arg mod "GOOD" '.[] | select(._id=="1234") | .int=.int + {stat: $mod}' tmp.json
`